# layout function with mar setting to zero

Tags: r, plot, graphics

```
x <- rnorm(10)
layout(rbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 4)), heights = c(1, 1), 
       widths = c(1, 1))
layout.show(4)
plot(rnorm(10))

par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(rnorm(10))
```

Why only the scales for x and y-axis are visible while their labels getting disappeared in the c(1, 2) plot?

Edited:

```
layout(rbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 4)), heights = c(1, 1), 
   widths = c(1, 1))

plotS <- function(x, y) {
  plot.new()
  plot.window(xlim = range(x), ylim = range(y))
  points(x, y)
  axis(1)
  mtext("Test12", 1, 3)
  axis(2)
  mtext("Test12", 2, 3)
  box()
}

par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plotS(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(rnorm(10))
```

However when you write your own plot function, axis labels drains to the plot below rather than totally getting missing.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have a good answer, but it looks like the axes are bleeding over into the adjacent left/below parts of the `layout`. Why the axis labels disappear is a good question.

Comment: @thelatemail I tried writing a new plot function. It drained axis labels to the one underneath. This is quite surprising.

Comment: Perhaps it's enough for a [`bug.report`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/bug.report.html)? Definitely seems quirky to me, and in all my time using `layout` I've never *tried* to do something like this ... now I can't wrap my brain around why ...

Comment: Setting `mar` doesn't crop the output. It only places/sizes the plot area. Stuff outside is still added (but outside the plot area).

Comment: @ekstroem But stuff outside includes (axis scale and axis labels). So why don't we see axis labels?